# Why am I much faster than the record, but not the record holder?

Tags: super-mario-maker

When playing other courses, some times it says the existing record is 99:59.999 seconds. I was obviously much faster, but I didn't get the record. What's gives? Also why is that such a common time to see. It is greater than the 500 seconds allowed.

Comment: That probably means that any clear time record has not been set yet. 99:59.99 sounds like a default upper limit time. If you have already beaten the level the time record it's probably broken.

Comment: @pinckerman that's what I thought too, but a) there's a name of someone who has that record and b) if I'm the first person who clears the level then they say "first clear" and have me as the record holder.

Comment: It is probably hacked data sent to the world record scoreboards.  People do this with all sorts of games all the time...

Comment: As pinckerman noted - That looks like a default upper limit. Think from a database perspective. Suppose someone managed to beat a level where the send data logs a timestamp outside the expected parameters. The code fetching the data and translating it into human form may not know how to make sense of an unexpected value, like blank, negative, over the limit, etc.  Chances are, if you see 99:59.999 it means someone exploited something and sent a bogus number just to keep themselves as the record holder. Where there's a leaderboard, there's always someone wanting to be on top.

Comment: "Think from a database perspective" might be how things are working, but if "think from the user perspective" doesn't work. Isn't that a bug?

Answer (score -1):

If you die, your run doesn't count. Dying after clearing a checkpoint will disable your record (for that run).